# NetSuite Send an email to all users who have a specific role in suite script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I try to send an email to all users who have the role of engineer,
I would like to find a function that send emails for all users according to their  roles,
or any function that returns me all the users by their role,
Is suite script includes one of those functions?

Answer (score 1):

Search for all employees with a particular role, then loop through them to send the email.  Here's an example of a scheduled script and a custom module that does this.

emailUtils.js

```js
/**
 *  @NAPIVersion 2.0
 *  @NModuleScope Public
 */
define(['N/email', 'N/search'], function(email, search) {
  function sendEmailToRole(emailObject, roleId) {
    var employeeIds = getEmployeesByRole(roleId);
    employeeIds.forEach(function(employeeId) {
      emailObject.recipients = employeeId;
      email.send(emailObject)
    });
  }

  function getEmployeesByRole(roleId) {
    var results = search.create({
      type: 'employee',
      filters: [
        ['isinactive', 'is', 'F'],
        'and', ['role', 'anyof', roleId]
      ]
    }).run().getRange({ start: 0, end: 1000 });

    return (results || []).map(function(result) {
      return result.id;
    })
  }

  return {
    sendEmailToRole: sendEmailToRole
  };
});
```

emailSchedule.js

```js
/**
 *  @NAPIVersion 2.0
 *  @NModuleScope Public
 *  @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */
define(['./emailUtils'], function(emailUtils) {
  function execute() {
    var ADMINISTRATOR = 3;

    var email = {
      author: 1073,
      subject: 'SUBJ: This is a test email',
      body: 'This is the body of the test email',
    };

    emailUtils.sendEmailToRole(email, ADMINISTRATOR);
  }

  return {
    execute: execute
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach I recommend would be to make a new Saved Search of the Employees with this role (and any other criteria you'd like met), then use that Saved Search to define a dynamic Entity Group (`Lists > Relationships > Groups > New`). You can then set this Group as the recipient of your email.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a saved search of employees where their role is Engineer. You can then use the sendEmail function to email each of those people